# RegEx replace all after and all before

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a file with about 2000 lines and the columns are divided with `,`.

I need to replace all dots `.`, that are after the 10th comma `,` with a comma. However, I do not replace any dots that are before that 10th comma on each line.

How can I make it replace all dots after the 10th comma with commas?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but this is a good regex to start with: `^([\w.]+.){10}(\w*).(\w*),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what:

```
(^(?:[^,\n]*,){10}[^.\n]*|(?!^)\G[^.\n]*).
```

Replace with:

```
$1,
```

Place the cursor at the beginning of the line. Then <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

### Explanation

```
(                           # Capturing group 1, whatever that stays the same
  ^(?:[^,\n]*,){10}[^.\n]*  # From the beginning of the line, skip 10 columns
                            # (with 10 commas), then skip to the nearest dot
  |                         # OR
  (?!^)\G[^.\n]*            # Continue from where the last dot matches
                            # and skip to the nearest dot
)
.                           # Dot, to be replaced
```

Comment: The OP wants to replace all periods after the tenth comma, with commas.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this regex:

```
(?:^(?:[^\R,]*,){10}|(?!^)\G)[^\R.]*\K\.
```

And replace with `,`.

Are you sure it's notepad++ v4.6? That version is pretty old and unfortunately, its regex capabilities won't support the above. The above works on v6.1.

```
(?:          # Beginning of non-capture group
  ^          # Match only at the start of the string
  (?:        # Beginning of non-capture group
    [^\R,]*  # Match non-newlines and non-comma characters
    ,        # Match commas
  ){10}      # Close of non-capture group and repeat 10 times
 |           # OR
  (?!^)\G    # A \G anchor that is not at the start to match from previous matches
)            # Close of non-capture group
[^\R.]*      # Match non-newlines and non-dot characters
\K           # Reset the matching
\.           # Match a dot
```